# Exclude column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ENSG | 3dir_S2_S23_L004_R1_001 | 7dir_S2_S25_L004_R1_001 | i3dir_S2_S29_L004_R1_001 | i7dir_S2_S31_L004_R1_001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG00000000003.15 | 349.0 | 183.0 | 199.0 | 165.0 |
| ENSG00000000419.13 | 133.0 | 82.0 | 190.0 | 168.0 |
| ENSG00000000457.14 | 62.0 | 56.0 | 95.0 | 111.0 |
| ENSG00000000460.17 | 191.0 | 122.0 | 300.0 | 285.0 |
| ENSG00000001036.14 | 507.0 | 286.0 | 326.0 | 317.0 |
| ENSG00000001084.13 | 205.0 | 192.0 | 310.0 | 320.0 |
| ENSG00000001167.14 | 406.0 | 324.0 | 379.0 | 309.0 |
| ENSG00000001460.18 | 93.0 | 78.0 | 146.0 | 120.0 |

I'm attempting to perform a calculation on each row of each column, excluding the column ENSG.

Something like this, where I divide each row value by the sum of the entire column:

```
df = df.transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```

How can I exclude the column ENSG from this calculation? Could I use iloc?

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` to exclude `ENSG` from columns then `transform` and `reset_index` after:

```
out = df.set_index('ENSG').transform(lambda x: x / x.sum()).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output:
                 ENSG  3dir_S2_S23_L004_R1_001  7dir_S2_S25_L004_R1_001  i3dir_S2_S29_L004_R1_001  i7dir_S2_S31_L004_R1_001
0  ENSG00000000003.15                 0.179342                 0.138322                  0.102314                  0.091922
1  ENSG00000000419.13                 0.068345                 0.061980                  0.097686                  0.093593
2  ENSG00000000457.14                 0.031860                 0.042328                  0.048843                  0.061838
3  ENSG00000000460.17                 0.098150                 0.092215                  0.154242                  0.158774
4  ENSG00000001036.14                 0.260534                 0.216175                  0.167609                  0.176602
5  ENSG00000001084.13                 0.105344                 0.145125                  0.159383                  0.178273
6  ENSG00000001167.14                 0.208633                 0.244898                  0.194859                  0.172145
7  ENSG00000001460.18                 0.047790                 0.058957                  0.075064                  0.066852
```

Comment: Yeah, I would need `ENSG` back in the dataframe.

Comment: @xonovi4031. I updated my answer according to your comment. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ENSG` is the first column, yes, you can use `iloc`:

```py
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:] / np.sum(df.iloc[:, 1:], axis=0)
```